# How to override superclasses update method properly in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have made a simple physics sprite that will automatically trigger update selector and move the sprite accordingly to the b2body member set.

However when I do subclass that physics sprite, I want to extend that update method to do some more actions. When I do override that update method I somehow need to call the super classes update method so it can do its business before I do my business in the subclass.

Here is some code:

Superclass:

```
    /**
 * SELECTOR
 * This selector updates the sprites position
 */
-(void) update:(ccTime) dt {
    CCLOG(@"PSprite update");
    if (self.body) {

        //Get the body's position in pixels
        CGPoint newLocationForSprite = ccp(self.body->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, self.body->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
        //positioning self
        [self setPosition:newLocationForSprite];
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime) dt {
//I want to call my superclass's update method
CCLOG(@"Subclass update");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

subclass code

```
- (void) update:(ccTime)dt
{
    [super update: dt];

    // do anything you want
}
```

Comment: It seems that it is not a public method, which it should be either, but for my case I needed it to be. Too bad their isn't protected in Objective C. i'll accept this